# Snowflake Recursive Query fails with "NULL result in a non-nullable column" error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've tracked down the issue to a couple of columns that indeed may return NULL. If I remove those values from the query, then it runs OK but I need them (legacy system).

The structure of the query is:

```
      WITH RECURSIVE CTE 
      (
        <anchor_clause> UNION ALL <recursive_clause>
      )
      SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Could you edit your question and add some simple data and the expected out ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't share data as the information in the tables queried is confidential...

Comment: Don't share production data, provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example] instead (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Include the DDL for the table(s) involved, enough sample data to illustrate the possible scenarios, the SQL you've managed to write so far, and the result you want to achieve based on your source data - all as editable text formatted appropriately.